# I can't get the video link

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I'm trying to get a link to a video, but I'm getting an error. I don't know how to fix this. I spent a lot of time looking for a way to fix it, but I don’t have the strength anymore. Help :)
My code:

```
from pytube import YouTube

link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9pmsuKWKf90"
yt = YouTube(link)
print(yt.streams)
itag = 137
url = YouTube(link).streams.get_by_itag(itag).url
print(url)
```

Traceback

```
  File "D:\Python\ffmpeg\link_video.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(yt.streams)
  File "D:\Python\ffmpeg\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 295, in streams
    self.check_availability()
  File "D:\Python\ffmpeg\venv\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 233, in check_availability
    raise exceptions.LiveStreamError(video_id=self.video_id)
pytube.exceptions.LiveStreamError: 9pmsuKWKf90 is streaming live and cannot be loaded
```

**Let me clarify: need to get a link to download the stream. The question is relevant**

Comment: Did you read the error message? Sorry if that sounds sarcastic, but it's pretty clear that that simply doesn't work or is not implemented.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt Of course I did. I wrote that I spent a lot of time trying to solve the problem. Perhaps there are hacks to solve this issue. Therefore, I asked a question here to those who may have encountered this problem. Thanks for your useless answer

Comment: This isn't a Python issue *per se*. You should be asking the author(s) of *pytube*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot print it because it is a livestream, and that functionality is not supported.

EDIT:
You can access data of a livestreamed video using the following code (m39SPyU3abg is the video id of a currently livestreaming video; it may not be live streaming when you use this code). I kept it in Python, but did not use Pytube, since Pytube is not designed for live streaming.

SECOND EDIT:
The url is constructed from the video_id. You do have the video_id, correct? If you also have the channel_id, you would not need to make an API call and could construct the url yourself. But if you do not have it, this code determines the channel_id and creates the url:

```
import requests

api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'

video_id = 'qlPLXYKoRIU'

url = f"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={video_id}&key={api_key}&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status"

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()

ab_channel= data['items'][0]['snippet']['channelId']
constructed_url = f"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}&ab_channel={ab_channel}"

print(constructed_url)
```

Comment: maybe you know other ways to get a link to the livestream?

Comment: @Мицок Are you willing to move away from pytube and access the YouTube API directly? If so, do you have a YouTube API key? (do NOT share it with me, I'm just asking if you have one)

Comment: The Python solution takes precedence (not necessarily pytube), but if there is no such solution, then I'm willing to consider all methods. I don't have a YouTube API, but that's not a problem, I can create one.

Comment: @Мицок I have edited my answer with a method using the Youtube API directly. Please clarify your question if this does not suffice.

Comment: "Am I misunderstanding your goal here?"
Yes a little. Your method does not allow me to get a link to download the stream. I made an API key, I’ll try to study its capabilities more deeply.

Comment: @Мицок Oh, I did not know you wanted to download it. I do not believe Youtube supports the ability to download a live stream.

Comment: @Мицок confirmed, you cannot download a video that’s being live streamed. Do you need it downloaded as it is being live streamed, or could you download it after the stream is done?

Comment: I need to start recording during the streaming. I record streamed using ffmpeg. But for this I need a link

Comment: Okay, if you are recording using a different method (im not very familar with ffmpeg), you only need to refer that method to a url?

Comment: I use something like this: ffmpeg -i "stream" -c copy output.mp4. So I used pytube to get the stream link. But pytube only returns links to videos that are no longer streaming. I will continue to look into this issue. There must be a solution :)

Comment: @Мицок I am still unsure on what data you are working with. If you have the video_id but not the channel_id, then I have updated my code for a working solution to provide the url.

Comment: I have a link to a YouTube page with a stream (for example, youtube.com/watch?v=CeG0JSBLqpk), I need to get a link to record the stream with ffmpeg (for example anotepad.com/notes/89pqecj6) I found a solution, but I don't like it. Perhaps someone here can suggest something else

Comment: I cannot answer your question if you don't clarify what you need. You need a link to the video, but youtube.com/watch?v=CeG0JSBLqpk is a link to your video. What is the issue? What solution did you find, and why is it not good enough? Update your question.